# Directory permissions SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, directory, user-permissions

I need some help regarding SQL Server 2008. What does it mean to have users with permissions to read & execute in the following directories:

```
\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn  
\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn  
\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Com
```

What exactly can they do?

Thanks in advance.